# How can I maximize, restore, or minimize a window with a vb script?

Tags: vbscript

I need to be able to make separte .vbs files that will (when triggered with a keyboard short-cut) will make the active window maximized, minimized, or restored.

How can I do this without downloading and installing (not allowed here) a separate package.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

VBScript and Windows Script Host don't provide intrinsic functions for maximizing/minimizing/restoring a window. Without any third-party tools, your only option is to use [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) to simulate keyboard the shortcuts of the corresponding commands in a window's system menu.

- To maximixe the active window, you can simulate the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> shortcut:

  ```
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.SendKeys "% x"
  ```
- To minimize the active window, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>:

  ```
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.SendKeys "% n"
  ```
- To restore the active window, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SpaceBar</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>:

  ```
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.SendKeys "% r"
  ```

(Note that this code won't work in non-English Windows versions, where the names of the Maximize/Minimize/Restore commands are localized and therefore have other shortcuts.)

Comment: I can get this to work with e.g. "calc". But for some reason not with "taskmgr". Any suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180036/sendkeys-in-vbscript-not-working-for-taskmgr

Answer (score 4):

SendKeys was not working in my computer. Spanish native with Spanish and English keyboard. I did this and worked in my code as instruction and worked to maximize my excel window. I put the .Sleep to visually check it.

```
objExcel.SendKeys"% x"
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.SendKeys"% x"

WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

To maximize any window, the following code will work:

```
Application.SendKeys "%{ }"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
Application.SendKeys "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

Topic is old. But I managed to find language independent solution. **SendKeys** can basically send any keys to application, including arrow keys and enter key. So we can emulate those actions without particular letters (x,r,n). Here is working example:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.SendKeys("% {DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")   'Maximize
'...
oShell.SendKeys("% {ENTER}")   'Restore
'...
oShell.SendKeys("% {DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")   'Minimize
```

Comment: For particular application you have to find the number of arrows before enter key. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in my Excel macro to maximise an external PDF document by executing the  shortcut keys 'Alt+Spacebar+x'.

Mote: '%' represents the Alt key, '( )' represents the spacebar key and 'x' represents the maximise key.

```
Application.SendKeys "%+( )+(x)", True
```