# Minimize a window via its pid

Tags: windows, cmd

My problem is that I want to minimize a window via batch file after window-start.

How to minimize a application-window from cmd? The pid is known. My OS is win7.

Comment: Are you opening it in the batch file? If so, use [`Start /min {x}`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005) - "***/min**   : Starts a new minimized Command Prompt window.*"

Comment: No, I doesn't start it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html):

```
nircmd win min process /pid
```

where `pid` is the process id of the window to minimize.

---

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - win](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

> `win [action] [find] [window to find] [Additional Parameters]`

...

> `[action]`: The action you want to do on the specified window:

...

> `min`: Minimizes the specified windows.

...

> `[find]`: The method to find the window

...

> `process`: Finds the desired window by specifying process ID (for example: /3412) or process name (for example: firefox.exe).

---

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Batch/VBScript solution which requires no additional software:

```
   @echo Off
   if \{%1\}==\{\} @echo Syntax: MinimizePID PID & goto :EOF
   if exist "%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs" del /f %TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs
   @echo dim  objArguments, pid>"%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs"
   @echo Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>>"%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs"
   @echo Set objArguments = Wscript.Arguments>>"%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs"
   @echo pid = objArguments(0)>>"%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs"
   @echo WshShell.AppActivate pid>>"%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs"
   @set "line=%%+ n"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   (
     @echo WshShell.SendKeys "!line!">>"%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs"
   )
   :doit
   cscript //nologo "%TEMP%\MinimizePID.vbs" %1
```

Assume pid.txt has the PID of the process whose window you want to minimize.  Save this batch file as MinimizePID.bat and invoke it in this way:

```
for /f %i in (pid.txt) do call MinimizePID %I
```

The only tricky part here was getting the SendKeys to work to send the Minimize window command.  You probably could code this as purely VBScript.  Also note this will work only on US Windows - key shortcuts are different in localized versions.

Thanks to [How can I maximize, restore, or minimize a window with a vb script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824284/how-can-i-maximize-restore-or-minimize-a-window-with-a-vb-script) for the approach.