# send an application from foreground to hidden window using vbs or cmd

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

Suppose I have a running application named `php.exe` and its PID in a text file named `php.pid`. This actually has no use to keep `php.exe` window in foreground. I have searched a lot but got no way to send it to hidden window. I am using `Windows 7 ultimate` edition. and need to do it by using command line or a vbs script, i have about 15+ window like this.

For vbs to run a hidden window we ca do this:

```
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.run "cmd /K php.exe & exit",0,true
Set sh = Nothing
```

but to sent this application from foreground to hidden window i can not fiend the method.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297085/minimize-a-window-via-its-pid

Comment: No, that question is for minimized window and i am asking to send an application to hidden window so that nobody can maximize that window and nobody can see that. @Mike Kelly

Comment: use php-win.exe to eliminate console window

Comment: thanks @ Tekno Sal; but i have 15+ nos window, like, httpd,tomcat, ftpd and so on...