# Start Firefox Minimized From Batch File

Tags: batch-file, firefox, cmd, windows-10

I've made a batch file that starts Firefox.

The goal is to make Firefox to start minimized.

I've tried `start /min "" "Path to Firefox.exe"`

I've tried to create a Firefox shortcut with the option to minimize window.

However neither of these ways work on Firefox while they work on other programs even on the batch file itself.

Also -s and -silent flags do nothing on Firefox.

I'm using Windows 10.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way proposed by @SometimesRight didn't work.

The solution is to install **Minimize On Start And Close** Firefox Add-On.

Tested on Windows 10 and Firefox 43.0.4.

You can download it here: [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimize-on-start-and-close/?src=api](http://Install%20Minimize%20On%20Start%20And%20Close)

Then in Firefox in the upper right menu (3 lines) choose **Add-Ons** and click on **Extensions** tab.

**Note: the first way below will always minimize Firefox when it starts and the BAT file that starts it.
The second way require the creation of additional VBS script and it will minimize focused Firefox from minimized BAT file by sending ESCAPE keystroke.**

**1.** Click on the **Options** button and check **Minimize on start**, uncheck everything else and set **Delay on start** to **500 ms** or higher if the Firefox needs more time to start.

Now create file in **Notepad** and save it as **Minimize.bat**

Copy and past the following code inside **.BAT** file:

```
@echo off
start "" "Path To Firefox"
```

Change **Path To Firefox** to **Firefox.exe** location.

You can also use **"firefox.exe"** instead of **"Path To Firefox"**.

If you want to start Firefox on specific website use **start "" "Path To Firefox" www.stackoverflow.com**

**Right-Click** on **Minimize.bat** file and select **Properties** (also you can select **Minimize.bat** file and press **ALT+ENTER** combination).

On **Shortcut** tab change **Window** property to **Minimized** and press **OK**.

Start this shortcut.

**2.** Click on the **Options** button and check **Minimize on ESC-press**, uncheck everything else.

Create file in **Notepad** and save it as **Minimize.vbs**

Copy and past the following code inside **.VBS** file:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "firefox"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Now create file in **Notepad** and save it as **Minimize.bat**

Copy and past the following code inside **.BAT** file:

```
@echo off
start "" "Path To Firefox"
timeout 2 /nobreak
wscript "Path To Minimize.vbs File"
```

Change **Path To Firefox** to **firefox.exe** location and **Path To Minimize.vbs File** to location of your Minimize.vbs file.

You can also use **"firefox.exe"** instead of **"Path To Firefox"**.

If you want to start Firefox on specific website use **start "" "Path To Firefox" www.stackoverflow.com**

You can change **timeout 2 /nobreak** to **timeout 3 /nobreak** to wait **3 seconds** for Firefox to start if it starts longer.

**Right-Click** on **Minimize.bat** file and select **Properties** (also you can select **Minimize.bat** file and press **ALT+ENTER** combination).

On **Shortcut** tab change **Window** property to **Minimized** and press **OK**.

Start this shortcut.

Comment: Wow, it's a shame that you have to jump through so many hoops to do such a simple thing! I wish I knew why `/min` worked for me on Windows 10 and Firefox 43.0.4 but I guess that's just one of many Microsoft Mysteries :-)

Comment: @SometimesRight the number of steps doesn't matter much as long as it does what is needed and the fact that something is usual doesn't make it simple. Everything depends only if you have a will to do something even knowing how much you need to do in order to move further :)  If it worked for me then I wouldn't be asking this question and we wouldn't be able to chat a little bit :) Thank you for your help :) Besides when I was searching I found a way how to compile a program into exe file in cmd without use of any additional program

Answer (score 1):

I expect Firefox automatically restores itself on startup. You could try using the -tray option to firefox:

```
start "" "Path to firefox" -tray
```

EDIT: the generic Mozilla option '-tray' does not seem to be supported for Firefox. However, the /min option to 'start' does work (for me!) on Windows 10 as long as there is no other instance of Firefox already running. If another instance is running its window will restore itself in the foreground when you run another start command even if you use /min.

If you want to start a second or subsequent instance minimized use Firefox's -new-window option:

```
start /min "" "Path to firefox" -new-window
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestion later @SometimesRight , typing from cell phone. Is there a way to switch off automatic restore in the Firefox settings?

Comment: I don't think so - I am only guessing that it does this because /min doesn't work. I have not tried -tray except that I know it doesn't work on Linux, it is however documented here:

Comment: I mean here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: If this will not work @SometimesRight is there a way to minize already opened Firefox from batch file?

Comment: There are third party utilities that will minimize an already open application, e.g. "nircmd", but it feels to me like you shouldn't need it. Have you tried making sure that no instances of Firefox are running before using /min? If Firefox is already running somewhere 'start'ing it will probably cause it to restore regardless of /min.

Comment: Yes the solution without using 3rd party programs is prefered @SometimesRight . I test it after restart of computer and after viewing Task Manager and there is no instance of Firefox running.

Comment: OK, I have just tried it with firefox using windows 7, and it works doing start /min firefox.exe, but only if there is not already a firefox running. Check with Task Manager that some other process has not started firefox...

Comment: Then probably -tray flag will work and I'll set this as a solution. For some reason /min doesn't work with no instance of Firefox running. Maybe someting have changed in Windows 10. Thank you @SometimesRight !

Comment: Just tried -tray; it doesn't work :-( But 'start /min "" "Path to firefox" -new-window' works even if there is another firefox running.

Comment: Ok if that will not work @SometimesRight I'll try with -new-window option

Comment: -new-window option didn't work for me if it was already running. if it isn't already running then it works either with or without -new-window

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have tried the method proposed by @samuel, but it did not work in my windows 11.
My solution is not to install any add-ons, but rather in conjunction with another thread:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824284/how-can-i-maximize-restore-or-minimize-a-window-with-a-vb-script)

Instead the content of Minimize.vbs in this thread, you can put this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "firefox"
WshShell.SendKeys "%{ }"
WshShell.SendKeys "n"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Besides, you don`t need to set any special propierties in the .bat file.