# SendKeys in VBScript not working for taskmgr

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

In Windows 10, I am using the exact same vbscript code once for "calc" and once for "taskmgr". Why does SendKeys (here alt+space) work for "calc" but not for "taskmgr"?

```
<package>
  <job id="vbs">
    <script language="VBScript">
      set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run "calc"
      WScript.Sleep 100
      WshShell.SendKeys "% "
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

(working as expected, drop down menu opens)

```
<package>
  <job id="vbs">
    <script language="VBScript">
      set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run "taskmgr"
      WScript.Sleep 100
      WshShell.SendKeys "% "
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

(not working, no drop down menu...)

Comment: For Windows 7, it is working. Can you try WshShell.SendKeys "%( )"?

Comment: @Kira Thanks for the suggestion. "%( )" behaves just like "% ": works for calc, not for taskmgr...

Comment: Is Task Manager running as Admin? If yes, is your script also running as Admin?

Comment: @Linus your code runs fine, drop down menu appears! Are you logged on to Windows 10 as Administrator or a Standard User?

Comment: @GTAVLover: The user I am logged on with has admin rights.

Comment: @Helen: As taskmgr is started from within my script, should it not have the same rights as the script itself? Or how can I check this?

Comment: I'll be damned! I just ran my wsf file with cscript from within an administrator console and here it worked!!

Comment: @Linus That must happen!

Comment: Are there any other ways to run the script as Administrator than to manually open an Administrator command line and run cscript?

Answer (score 0):

All right. Thank you all for your help in the comments.
So, for sendKeys to work for taskmgr, the script has to be run as administrator. This can be done by openning a Command Prompt as Administrator and then

```
cscript myScript.wsf
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a second keystroke.
For me this works:

```
DIM shell

SET shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

shell.Run "taskmgr.exe", 1, False
WScript.Sleep(100)
shell.SendKeys "% "
shell.SendKeys "n" '<- this is what you might have missed
```

but it only works if run by the same user (note that you cannot have two instances of the taskmgr running at the same time. When there is an "old" instance than this instance will be brought to foreground and no new instance will be created, even if the "old" instance is running under a different user. In this case you might need to close/kill the "old" instance with `taskkill /im taskmgr.exe`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the OP issue that a non admin task may not address an admin level task there are other "potential" causes to related send keys misbehaviour.

One is timing due to a slow loading app (or slow system) so you may need bigger sleeps, the other is during such slow loading the window focus for sendkeys may be retained by a script or taken control of by another window. A classic case can be a cmd file keeps or needs to be the sendkeys focus. So always include in a Batch.cmd a unique title.

```
<package>
 <job id="vbs">
    <script language="VBScript">
      DIM WshShell
      SET WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run "taskmgr.exe", 1, False
' For sendkeys to work effectively the wait time must be related to the time it takes to slow load a new app
      WScript.Sleep 1500
' For sendkeys to work effectively the focus should ensure another script is not currently focused after the delay
' The AppActivate "Name" should be a unique window so for a CMD window use a "Title" in its startup
      WshShell.AppActivate "Task Manager"
      WshShell.SendKeys "% "
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

typical.vbs

```
DIM WshShell
      SET WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k Title Hello", 1, False
' For sendkeys to work effectively the wait time must be related to the time it takes to slow load a new app
      WScript.Sleep 500
' For sendkeys to work effectively the focus should ensure another script is not currently focused after the delay
' The AppActivate "Name" should be a unique window so for a CMD window use a "Title" in its startup
      WshShell.AppActivate "Hello"
      WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World!"
```