# What is Application.Sendkeys for "Windows" key in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

There is no documentation of "windows" key :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys

I wanted a combination of "Windows+UP" key to **Maximize Active window**.
So, I tried "Ctrl+Esc" for windows key + {UP} : *Application.SendKeys ("^({ESC}{UP})")*  but it didn't work.

Is there a way to send windows key using API, dll etc without using external programs like *AutoIt*.

Comment: Have you tried sending F11? Few shortcut cheatsheets will show it may work

Comment: It seems to work for some programs but sadly, It didn't work for my Application !

Comment: Aye gotcha - have a look here @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824284/how-can-i-maximize-restore-or-minimize-a-window-with-a-vb-script some approaches here may work hopefully

Comment: Wow, It did work ! Thanks . How can i mark your answer as solution ?

Comment: Added as an answer; happy to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to send windows key using API, dll etc without using external programs like AutoIt

Yes, you can use [FindWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml) and [ShowWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/ShowWindow.shtml) API to maximize a window. This is more reliable than using Sendkeys.

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Sub MaximizeAWindow()
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim Caption As String
    
    Caption = "THIS IS THE CAPTION OF THE WINDOW"
    
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Caption)
    
    If hwnd <> 0 Then
        ShowWindow hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to find the window. Is the caption correct?"
    End If
End Sub
```

You may be also interested in [GetForegroundWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetForegroundWindow.shtml) and the [GetWindowText](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetWindowText.shtml) API to get the caption of the current active window?

Comment: Wow !! Been looking this for days. Couldn't find this way of solution so went to Application.Sendkeys route ! THANKS !

Comment: `Couldn't find this way of solution so went to Application.Sendkeys route ! THANKS ! – 
Pramod Pandit
 5 hours ago` Do not go to Application.Sendkeys **route**. Go to API **rout**... Ok Ok.. that was a bad one... :D